# Why can't pip install the metar distribution even though it's in the search results?

Tags: python, pip

I'm not well-versed in `pip` as I would like but I'm finding this behavior strange.  I want to install the `metar` package.  I find it when I search:

```
[user@host project]$ pip search metar
...
metar                     - Metar - a package to parse METAR coded weather
                            reports
```

However, when I try to install it:

```
[user@host project]$ pip install metar
Downloading/unpacking metar
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement metar
Cleaning up...
No distributions at all found for metar
Storing complete log in /home/user/.pip/pip.log
```

If the package shows up in the search results, why can't I install it?

Answer (score 0):

If it is an external download and unverified, you can try the following:

```
pip install metar --allow-unverified metar
```